# Creating a VS .Net 2003 property macro/variable

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like to create a macro/variable for my project properties, similar to `$(ConfigurationName)`, `$(OutDir)`, etc - without making environment variables.  I've found that this can be done in later versions of Visual Studio, but I do not have the option of updating my IDE.  Can this be done in the .Net 2003 version (if so, how?) - or is the only way to do this through environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this cannot be done in VS .Net 2003 except by using environment variables.